# Execute AJAX loaded HTML5

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, prototype

For my CMS I'm loading the contents with AJAX (using Prototype). THe new Javascript I'm executing by Prototype's internal method string.evalScripts(). This works fine. But now I saw that HTML5-Elements like the video-tag isn't executed. The code is there, but the browser doesn't show it.
How do I execute these HTML5-Elements?

Comment: Please paste some code in here (neatly..with indents).  Thanks

Comment: For what? There is no try to execute the HTML5-Elements. I need a way to execute it. This needs a generall answer like "You can execute HTML5-elements by using Prototype's function string.executeHTML5()."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a stone a threw it on me. It is executed, but I used relative paths. So the paths were wrong.